# Plotly: How to avoid text in scatter plot being cut when exporting to PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, export, plotly

I have the following code to make an scatter plot using plotly as px

```
fig1 = px.scatter(utilities, x="Rating", y="Spread", facet_col="Duration",text="Security_Name")
fig1.update_layout(width=1200,title_text='Spread por rating y duración en el sector Utilities')
fig1.update_traces(textfont_size=8,textposition='top right')
fig1.show()
```

The problem is that when I export `fig1` to PDF using this code:

```
fig1.write_image("Utilities.pdf")
```

Then most of the texts in `"text"` are cut because names are too long (they cannot be shortened). I have already tried using `"top center"` and `"top left"` but in either case the text is cut. I would really appreciate your help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pj6F.png)

[image]

#### Update: Status after upgrading plotly: I have shortened the strings a little bit.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a dataset, but I've been able to reproduce your problem with a subset of a similar dataset `px.data.stocks` and an approach that resembles your use of `px.scatter`. And I'm assuming that your data has a long format, but that's not too important. What's important is this:

1. You're absolutely right, the text will be cut using `px.Scatter([...] text = <text>)`
2. There does surprisingly not seem to be a direct way to fix this.
3. I've produced a work-around that's more than a bit hacky.
4. The work-around turns this:

[image]

...into this:

[image]

The following snippet will reproduce the plot above. If this is something you can use, I'd be happy to elaborate on the details. But the short story is this: Faceted plots makes room for annotations made from `add_annotations()`, but not from annotations using `px.Scatter([...] text = <text>)`.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
df = df[df.columns[:4]]
df2 = pd.melt(df.iloc[0:3],
              id_vars=['date'],
              value_vars=df.columns[1:],
              var_name='stock',
              value_name='value')

# your approach
fig = px.scatter(df2, x="date", y="value", facet_col="stock", text = 'stock')
fig.update_layout(width=1200,title_text='Spread por rating y duración en el sector Utilities')
fig.update_traces(textfont_size=8, textposition='top right')

# annotations
for c, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    for i, y in enumerate(d.y):      
        fig.add_annotation(x=d.x[i], y=d.y[i], text = str(d.x[i]),
                           font=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)",size=10),
                           showarrow = False,
                           xanchor = 'left',
                           row = 1, col = c + 1
                          )
        
fig.write_image('c:\plotlyplots\subnotation.pdf')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hello vestland, im pretty sure I didn't understand the code you sent me. I tried to run this all from " #your approach "and get the messsage 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_annotation

Comment: @JCUBROD Check if `fig` is defined. And let me know what plotly version you are running.

Comment: ,4.1.0rc1 is the version.

Comment: Fig is defined here                                                                                                      fig = px.scatter(utilities, x="Rating", y="Spread", facet_col="Duration",text="Security_Name")
fig.update_layout(width=1200,title_text='Spread por rating y duración en el sector Utilities')
fig.update_traces(textfont_size=8,textposition='top right')

Comment: That is an OLD version. Please consider updating.

Comment: @JCUBROD According to [the docs](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases) `add_annotation()` is available from `v4.12`

Comment: Thank yoy vetsland, it worked with the upgrated plotly!!!

Comment: @JCUBROD Cool! In that case, would you consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just checked the PDF gotten from the code and they are still showing several names being cut

Comment: @JCUBROD OK.... insert a screenshot in your question under `Update: Status after upgrading plotly`. You do have some extremely long strings though...

Comment: done. I have shortened the strings a little, more is not possible